# Real time refreshing chat using jQuery $.Ajax for both computers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

I found a script for real chat using $.ajax jQuery, but it refereshes only my massages. For example:
I write to You: Hello, this message refresh for me.
You write to me: Hey, to see your message I must refresh a site by clicking F5, but You do not have to click F5. Something wrong!

My $.ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#lupnijto").click(function (e) {
    $("#lupnijto").hide();
    $("#LoadingImage").show();

    var zeszyt_value = 'zeszyt='+ $("#contentText").val(); //build a post data structure

    jQuery.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "response.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: zeszyt_value,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#responds").prepend(response);
            $("#contentText").val('');
            $('#contentText').focus();

            $("#lupnijto").show();
            $("#LoadingImage").hide();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $("#lupnijto").show();
            $("#LoadingImage").hide();
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
 });
```

What am I doing wrong? Why data only refreshes for me? How the chat works? Am I doing it correct? I accept answers. Thanks.

Comment: For a realtime chat system to work, you need socket.io with node js (simplest) or similar technologies. With ajax it is only polling.

Comment: You need to regularly check the server for new messages using AJAX, otherwise your browser can't know if there was something new there or not.

Comment: As above, you currently only perform an ajax request when you send a message. You must also perform a request every x (period of time) to check for replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such real time applications, you need to use WebSockets: [On MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets)
,you can also check on some WebSockets API [Socketio](http://socket.io/) for Node.js
I do advice those, but also you can use AJAX (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Socket.IO. For non-WebSockets browsers you can use [Engine.IO](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io).

Comment: Thanks You. Is it possible to send CSS style and jQuery slides using socket.io or only text?

Comment: @glapa.wojciech No problem, CSS styles its text too. But why you need to send CSS on server?